# Flutter Project Not Launching on IOS Simulator

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

When I try to launch the default Flutter app on my oOS simulator (version 14.5), I get an error message saying:

> "Runner quit unexpectedly"

I attached the Problem Details and System Configuration report to the bottom of this post. Does anyone else have this issue or know how to fix it? I've tried wiping the simulators and creating an entirely new Flutter project but neither worked.

---

````
CrashReporter Key:   IDK if this is sensitive but I'm redacting it
Hardware Model:      Macmini9,1
Process:             Runner [22475]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85498A85-DCD0-4FB9-82EE-794AE9FDBD1D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/447DA17F-A27F-4676-980A-20CACFEBC45C/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.example.flutterCompleteGuide
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [22063]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.85498A85-DCD0-4FB9-82EE-794AE9FDBD1D [5919]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [2216]

Date/Time:           2021-06-15 10:42:55.3798 -0400
Launch Time:         2021-06-15 10:42:54.4896 -0400
OS Version:          macOS 12.0 (21A5248p)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4298858496
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      mapped file                 1003b6000-1003ba000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=4c916b85
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [22475]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:



Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7fff2bbd8 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1003eae5c ???
2   dyld                                   0x20051a88f dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 890
3   dyld                                   0x2005196b5 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 244
4   dyld                                   0x2005194b4 start + 388
5   dyld                                   0x200514000 ???

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7fff18320 ???
1   ???                                 0x7ff7fff311a0 ???


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000108441af8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000108ade000
   r8: 0x9894d64da077006c   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000108ade000  r11: 0x0000000108901010
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000108901060  r14: 0x0000000200588080  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: <unavailable>       rfl: 0x0000000000000283
 tmp0: 0x00000001003d8c64 tmp1: 0x00000001003d7f8c tmp2: 0x0000000200532ca3


Binary Images:
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???
       0x200514000 -        0x20057bfff dyld (*) <4e207376-cc5d-3986-a0bd-4d09f4217e68> /usr/lib/dyld

EOF

Model: Macmini9,1, BootROM 7429.0.72.0.3, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi, wl0: May  4 2021 18:24:35 version 18.20.281.2.7.8.107 FWID 01-7c11bd60
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: webcam
USB Device: Dell USB Entry Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of this Problem is macOS Monterey (macOS 12.0), which you are using after seeing the Crash-Report.

I just recently installed the new Beta (also on M1) and am sadly having the same Problem now. Maybe they fix it with the next Update, which should come in the next couple of days/weeks.